# Android App Not Available For Download on Some Devices

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility, device

I'm facing an issue where the app is not available for download on certain devices that should be well supported, the listing just doesn't up in Google Play.

I see about 1800 devices on the Not Supported list for the APK via the dev console. Among them some Galaxy S3, S4, S5 models (the list has multiple variants of same device). About 6577 appear on the Supported list.

I have entries in the Manifest to support different screen sizes and densities, here's my manifest section:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foo"
    android:versionCode="57"
    android:versionName="2.0.5" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"  />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <permission android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- Permission to read Google Services -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"  />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".fooApp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="foo.db" />
        <meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
        <meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="false" />
        <meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.foo" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="... key ..." />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"  />

        <activity android:name=".StatusActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" />
        <activity android:name=".StatusDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".MyAlertsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".AlertLinesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".AlertDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"  />
        <activity android:name=".RouteListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" />
        <activity android:name=".StopListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".StopTimesActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".UpgradeActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name=".TransfersActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" />
        <activity android:name=".TransfersDetailsActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MyDialog" />
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.VPI" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".TabHostActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".Service.NotificationService" />              

        <receiver android:name="com.foo.Receiver.MyAlarmReceiver"  />

        <receiver android:name="com.foo.Receiver.ConnectionChangedReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>     

        <receiver android:name="com.foo.Receiver.BootCompletedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Among filtered devices are: Galaxy Note Edge, and some other mainstream devices, some Samsung tablets and Asus tablets are filtered out as well. Howerever works fine for Nexus 7.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: can you remove the support-screens tag and try again? if you set true to all of them you don't need to specify them

Comment: How about resizeable and anyDensity tags? remove the whole thing?

Comment: remove the whole thing yes

Comment: post all manifest file............

Comment: This didnt change anything. Could it be <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" /> Open GL 2?

Comment: I've updated the post with full manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<uses-feature>` instead of `<uses-permission>` in your manifest file & set `android:required="false"` for the features..

So replace

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<permission android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<!-- Permission to read Google Services -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"  />
```

with

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" ></uses-feature >
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"  android:required="false" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"  android:required="false" />
<uses-feature  android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" ></uses-feature >
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" ></uses-feature >
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false" ></uses-feature >

<uses-feature android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"  android:required="false" />

<!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<uses-feature android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" android:required="false" />
<!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<uses-feature android:name="com.foo.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:required="false" />

<!-- Permission to read Google Services -->
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"   android:required="false" />
```

Check if the App is available for download on more number of devices after making this change..

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick and adds 1200+ devices. Some Galaxy devices are now on the accepted list, which I don't get all Galaxy 3,4,5s & Notes should support GPS / Location & storage. This is somewhat puzzling, does each manufacturer handle that somehow differently?

Comment: Well, i'm not sure about that..might be... ;)

Comment: This seems like a dangerous solution and I'm almost sure that this will cause main functions in your app to break. `uses-feature` and `uses-permission` are COMPLETELY different and used for different things. read more on the following link: https://endocode.com/blog/2014/02/04/android-permissions-features-and-google-play-store/

permissions usualy explicitly add features but the way to handle that is to make the FEATURE optional and not replace all `uses-permission` with `uses-feature` as it will most likely cause a `SecurityException` or simply won't work

Answer (score 2):

first of all remove following code from manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

and check which particular device group you are losing,  this may happen that you are losing very old api version device which now a times people are not using

and for more information you can refer following link

https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove :

```
"<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />"
```

Check if you have localisations created for each supported language. And add screenshots on play store taken from device with 4", 5", 6" and/or tablet.
Also set android:targetSdkVersion to 21. 
This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`aapt`](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Project-aapt-Android-Asset-Packaging-Tool.html) tool to see what implied features exist in your manifest and make them optional by adding `<uses-feature android:name="FREATURE_NAME" android:required="false" />` to these features.
Also, make sure your app does not break when these features are not available on the device by using the following method to check the availability of the optional feature in your app:

```
protected boolean hasHardwareFeature(Context context, String feature)
{
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(feature))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device doesn't have hardware feature " + feature);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Try too add this

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"
        tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" />
```

If this is in a Android Studio Project you need to set the min/max in the app/build.gradle file

A other possibility is that you have a dimens, layout or drawable sat to a specific device size/type or screen resolution.

Comment: This had no effect. I removed the entire tag, uploaded to dev console however the number of supported devices remained the same.

Comment: Else if you import your project in to android studios that might do the trick

Comment: Didnt work. tools:ignore="OldTargetApi" had no effect. Moving minSdkVersion up to 13 makes the apk loose 1336 devices. That makes it loose all Gingerbread devices, still ~6% market share.

Comment: Is this a Android Studio project or eclipse?